# Which database to use with Django?

Tags: python, database, django

I installed Django, and started working through the tutorial. It told me that I had to choose which database I would use. Here are the options...

1. 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
2. 'django.db.backends.postgresql'
3. 'django.db.backends.mysql'
4. 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
5. 'django.db.backends.oracle'

The only work I have done with databases has been working with mysql in PHP. What are the differences between these, and which should I use.

Comment: You should use the one that fits the needs of your application and environment best - this isn't something anyone else can decide. (For the tutorial, stick to sqlite.) Also, "please research five database systems for me" is way too broad for SO.

Comment: @Inerdial I'm just doing this for a learning experience, and have basically no experience with databases. I didn't ask anyone to research them, I just thought that someone here would know about them and care to explain.

Comment: Since this is primarily a learning experience, just use sqlite3 for now while you're learning Django. Later, when working on a real project, you'll have to decide which db to use based on requirements. If all else is equal, just use mysql since you already know it. Long story short: for learning Django it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can eliminate Oracle because it is proprietary.

SQLite is quite different because the database is a file, there is no need for a running daemon.

MySQL and PostgreSQL are quite similar. If using postgres then psycopg is supposed to be faster - however be careful because [2.4.2 is not compatible with Django 1.3.1](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16250).

If you have time, it would be great for you to learn about PostgreSQL. If you don't, stick to MySQL which you know.

Comment: As a note, while MySQL and PostgreSQL are similar, they are configured quite a bit differently (with PostgreSQL being a bit harder), but PostgreSQL is also quite a bit faster than MySQL. It really depends on the needs of your application and environment and also what you are comfortable with taking on.